# EF core 2.1 using take in projection

Tags: c#, .net-core, ef-core-2.1

I want to use Take() in projection but I dont want to produce N+1 query, in addition without Take() in projection I'm facing with performance issue.
I used Take() with EF6 but I faced with N+1 issue on EF Core.

example projection:

```
source.Select(post => new PostProject
            {
                PostDisableCoins = post.PostDisableCoins
                                    .OrderBy(x=>x.CoinAmount)
                                    .Take(3)
                                    .ToList(),
                WarStartTime = post.WarStartTime,
                WarEndTime = post.WarEndTime,
                WarWinner = post.WarWinner,
                WarDeclarer = post.WarDeclarer
            });
```

I want to have Take(3) whithout N+1, any suggestion?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is EF Core 2.1 implementation defect. Following is the workaround, but use it only if you really have performance issues, because it requires breaking the navigation property join abstraction and using manual join, which I always say should not be used with EF (Core). Also might not work if used to project more than one collection, or as part of a more complex query.

It requires replacing the usage of the collection navigation property `post.PostDisableCoins` with `SelectMany` using lateral join and hiding the `OrderBy` / `Take` operators (update with proper types and PK/FK names):

```
var postDisableCoinsQuery = source.SelectMany(p =>
    db.Set<PostDisableCoin>()
        .Where(c => c.PostId == p.Id)
        .OrderByDescending(c => c.CoinAmount)
        .Take(3)
);
```

Then do `GroupJoin` to it:

```
var query = 
    from p in source
    join c in postDisableCoinsQuery on p.Id equals c.PostId into postDisableCoins
    select new PostProject
    {
        PostDisableCoins = postDisableCoins.ToList(),
        WarStartTime = p.WarStartTime,
        WarEndTime = p.WarEndTime,
        WarWinner = p.WarWinner,
        WarDeclarer = post.WarDeclarer
    };
```

When executed, the above will produce the desired result with single SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

Please note the doc regarding [EF core 2.1 new features:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.1)

> We have improved our query translation to avoid executing "N + 1" SQL
>   queries in many common scenarios in which the usage of a navigation
>   property in the projection leads to joining data from the root query
>   with data from a correlated subquery. ***The optimization requires
>   buffering the results from the subquery, and we require that you
>   modify the query to opt-in the new behavior***.

for example:

```
var query = context.Customers.Select(
    c => c.Orders.Where(o => o.Amount  > 100).Select(o => o.Amount).ToList());
```

Notice where the `.ToList()` is included.

You need to modify your projection query accordingly, in order to enable the optimization feature.

---

**In your case it might be:**

```
source.Select(post => new PostProject
            {
                PostDisableCoins = post.PostDisableCoins
                                    .Select(x => x.OrderBy(x=>x.CoinAmount))
                                    .Select(x => x) 
                                    .Take(3)                                  
                                    .ToList(),
                WarStartTime = post.WarStartTime,
                WarEndTime = post.WarEndTime,
                WarWinner = post.WarWinner,
                WarDeclarer = post.WarDeclarer
            });
```

Comment: when you .Select(x => x.OrderBy(x=>x.CoinAmount).Take(3)), x is not list no longer and I can not order it or use take function.

Comment: Then try .`Select(x => x.OrderBy(x=>x.CoinAmount)).Select(x => x).Take(3).ToList()` :) But twirk with it a little bit, it will give you good insights.

Comment: This answer doesn't make sense. OP already put the *opt in* `ToList` in the proper place. The problem is that the optimization is incomplete and apparently doesn't handle this scenario (doesn't fall into *many common scenarios* :)

Comment: @BarrJ I read that new features, but I think it's kind of bugs in vs, becaus I'm expecting a list after select but x at that select returns single object

Comment: @Mehdi might be, I would suggest you look deeper into it.